# GoogleAds Performance Max campaign getting no traffic even after tROAS optimisation

Tags: google-ads, traffic, ppc

I created Performance Max campaign in GoogleAds 2 months ago and it barely gets any traffic.
After some time, I optimised it towards target return on spend (tROAS) and I increased budget in order to get enough traffic with a hope it would get enough data to work on tROAS optimisation, but I still barely see any spend and it's not hitting actual conversion goals.

What action plan would be useful in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work through the various metrics to diagnose what might be causing the problem. Based on your description of few clicks, here's the first few things I would check:

Are you seeing plenty of impressions, but few clicks? That may represent an issue with your ad assets. Depending on what type of ads are being served what constitutes a good CTR would vary, but trying new assets might see an improvement here.

Or are your ads not showing very often? Very low impressions would suggest that there's something wrong. You said you've increased your budget, so that shouldn't be the issue. It may be your ad assets aren't serving because there are issues with them. Check the status of the ads and correct any that are disapproved or limited. You should also look to see if your assets are rated as low strength.

Low impressions might also be down to a problem with location targeting, make sure you've got a large enough audience and you've not accidentally blocked out part of your marketplace with a location exclusion. Also, make sure your language targeting is correct.

Does your campaign use a merchant centre feed? Make sure it's working properly and there aren't any issues being reported in Google Merchant Centre.

Have you set any audience signals? Make sure they're relevant and not too restrictive. Google will often try to target users outside of those signals, but you  can't rely on that.

Do you have good conversion goals which are being correctly tracked and values being passed to Ads? The algorithm Google uses for targeting your ads depends upon users actually converting on your website, so making sure that this data is correct is vital.